# Is there a way to find all PNG files in a folder that have transparent pixels

Tags: files, search, images, png

I have a couple thousand PNGs, all of them probably support the alpha channel but only some of them actually use it (Only some of them actually have transparent pixels).

Is there any way at all for me to quickly find all such files?